# Ryu fakeGateway/Router

Tags: gateway, mininet, sdn, pox, ryu

I am trying to code a fake gateway similar to [this one in pox](https://github.com/noxrepo/pox/blob/carp/pox/forwarding/l3_learning.py#L5):  to send packets between h1(10.1.1.2) and h2(10.1.4.2) in mininet

My gateway has two interfaces, one in 10.1.1.0/24 (ip: 10.1.1.1) and one in 10.1.4.0/24 (ip:10.1.4.1)

I am trying with h1 to download a video from apache webserver running on h2.

When I do so, h1 sends an ARP request to find who has 10.1.1.1?
 I already coded a function to reply to these arp requests and my switch answers: 00:00:00:00:00:01 (S1-eth0 mac)

Now h1 sends TCP packets with src 10.1.1.2 to 10.1.4.2 and h2 receives them but drops them because the dst mac is 00:00:00:00:00:01. I added something to change the mac to 00:00:00:00:00:02 in my code but so far it is not working and the mac stays 00:00:00:00:00:01 according to tcpdump.

Could someone please tell me if my reasoning is wrong? Moreover what is wrong with my code? If there is a working example of something similar could you please send me a link? I found the ryu rest router but it is not very prone to modification which is why I started coding this.

(You will have to configure routing for h1 and h2 in order for s1 to get packets)
Thank you in advance.

My code is the following

```
# Copyright (C) 2011 Nippon Telegraph and Telephone Corporation.
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or
# implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

from ryu.base import app_manager
from ryu.controller import ofp_event
from ryu.controller.handler import CONFIG_DISPATCHER, MAIN_DISPATCHER
from ryu.controller.handler import set_ev_cls
from ryu.lib.packet import arp
from ryu.ofproto import ofproto_v1_4
from ryu.lib.packet import packet
from ryu.lib.packet import ethernet
from ryu.lib.packet import ether_types
from ryu.lib.packet import ipv4
from ryu.lib.packet import icmp
from ryu.lib.packet.arp import arp
from ryu.lib.packet.packet import Packet
import array

HOST_IPADDR1 = "10.1.1.2"
HOST_IPADDR2 = "10.1.4.2"
ROUTER_IPADDR1 = "10.1.1.1"
ROUTER_IPADDR2 = "10.1.4.1"
ROUTER_MACADDR1 = "00:00:00:00:00:01"
ROUTER_MACADDR2 = "00:00:00:00:00:02"
ROUTER_PORT1 = 1
ROUTER_PORT2 = 2

class SimpleSwitch14(app_manager.RyuApp):
    OFP_VERSIONS = [ofproto_v1_4.OFP_VERSION]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SimpleSwitch14, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.mac_to_port = {}
        self.arpTable = {}#ip to mac

    @set_ev_cls(ofp_event.EventOFPSwitchFeatures, CONFIG_DISPATCHER)
    def switch_features_handler(self, ev):
        datapath = ev.msg.datapath
        ofproto = datapath.ofproto
        parser = datapath.ofproto_parser

        # install table-miss flow entry
        #
        # We specify NO BUFFER to max_len of the output action due to
        # OVS bug. At this moment, if we specify a lesser number, e.g.,
        # 128, OVS will send Packet-In with invalid buffer_id and
        # truncated packet data. In that case, we cannot output packets
        # correctly.  The bug has been fixed in OVS v2.1.0.
        match = parser.OFPMatch()
        actions = [parser.OFPActionOutput(ofproto.OFPP_CONTROLLER,
                                          ofproto.OFPCML_NO_BUFFER)]
        self.add_flow(datapath, 0, match, actions)

    def add_flow(self, datapath, priority, match, actions):
        ofproto = datapath.ofproto
        parser = datapath.ofproto_parser

        inst = [parser.OFPInstructionActions(ofproto.OFPIT_APPLY_ACTIONS,
                                             actions)]

        mod = parser.OFPFlowMod(datapath=datapath, priority=priority,
                                match=match, instructions=inst)
        datapath.send_msg(mod)

    def receive_arp(self,datapath,packet,etherFrame,inPort):
        arpPacket = packet.get_protocol(arp)
        if arpPacket.opcode == 1 :
            arp_dstIp = arpPacket.dst_ip
            self.logger.debug('received ARP Request %s => %s (port%d)'%(etherFrame.src,etherFrame.dst,inPort))
            self.reply_arp(datapath,etherFrame,arpPacket,arp_dstIp,inPort)
        elif arpPacket.opcode == 2 :
            pass

    def reply_arp(self, datapath, etherFrame, arpPacket, arp_dstIp, inPort):
        dstIp = arpPacket.src_ip
        srcIp = arpPacket.dst_ip
        dstMac = etherFrame.src
        self.logger.debug("ARP dstIp: %s"%arp_dstIp)
        if arp_dstIp == ROUTER_IPADDR1:
            srcMac = ROUTER_MACADDR1
            outPort = ROUTER_PORT1
        elif arp_dstIp == ROUTER_IPADDR2:
            srcMac = ROUTER_MACADDR2
            outPort = ROUTER_PORT2
        else:
            self.logger.debug("unknown arp request received !")
        self.send_arp(datapath, 2, srcMac, srcIp, dstMac, dstIp, outPort)
        self.logger.debug("send ARP reply %s => %s (port%d)" %(srcMac, dstMac, outPort))

    def send_arp(self, datapath, opcode, srcMac, srcIp, dstMac, dstIp, outPort):
        if opcode == 1:
            targetMac = "00:00:00:00:00:00"
            targetIp = dstIp
        elif opcode == 2:
            targetMac = dstMac
            targetIp = dstIp
        e = ethernet.ethernet(dstMac, srcMac, ether_types.ETH_TYPE_ARP)
        a = arp(1, 0x0800, 6, 4, opcode, srcMac, srcIp, targetMac, targetIp)
        p = Packet()
        p.add_protocol(e)
        p.add_protocol(a)
        p.serialize()
        actions = [datapath.ofproto_parser.OFPActionOutput(outPort, 0)]
        out = datapath.ofproto_parser.OFPPacketOut(
            datapath=datapath,
            buffer_id=0xffffffff,
            in_port=datapath.ofproto.OFPP_CONTROLLER,
            actions=actions,
            data=p.data)
        datapath.send_msg(out)

    def _send_packet(self, datapath, port, pkt):
        ofproto = datapath.ofproto
        parser = datapath.ofproto_parser
        pkt.serialize()
        self.logger.info("packet-out %s" % (pkt,))
        data = pkt.data
        actions = [parser.OFPActionOutput(port=port)]
        out = parser.OFPPacketOut(datapath=datapath,
                                  buffer_id=ofproto.OFP_NO_BUFFER,
                                  in_port=ofproto.OFPP_CONTROLLER,
                                  actions=actions,
                                  data=data)
        datapath.send_msg(out)

    def _handle_icmp(self, datapath, port, pkt_ethernet, pkt_ipv4, pkt_icmp):
        if pkt_icmp.type != icmp.ICMP_ECHO_REQUEST:
            return
        pkt = packet.Packet()
        pkt.add_protocol(ethernet.ethernet(ethertype=pkt_ethernet.ethertype,
                                           dst=pkt_ethernet.src,
                                           src=ROUTER_MACADDR1))
        pkt.add_protocol(ipv4.ipv4(dst=pkt_ipv4.src,
                                   src=ROUTER_IPADDR1,
                                   proto=pkt_ipv4.proto))
        pkt.add_protocol(icmp.icmp(type_=icmp.ICMP_ECHO_REPLY,
                                   code=icmp.ICMP_ECHO_REPLY_CODE,
                                   csum=0,
                                   data=pkt_icmp.data))
        self._send_packet(datapath, port, pkt)

    @set_ev_cls(ofp_event.EventOFPPacketIn, MAIN_DISPATCHER)
    def _packet_in_handler(self, ev):
        msg = ev.msg
        datapath = msg.datapath
        ofproto = datapath.ofproto
        parser = datapath.ofproto_parser
        in_port = msg.match['in_port']
        pkt = packet.Packet(msg.data)
        eth = pkt.get_protocols(ethernet.ethernet)[0]
        self.logger.info('%s'%eth.ethertype)
        dst = eth.dst
        src = eth.src
        dpid = datapath.id
        self.mac_to_port.setdefault(dpid, {})

        if eth.ethertype == ether_types.ETH_TYPE_LLDP:
            # ignore lldp packet
            return
        self.logger.info("packet in dpid: %s, srce: %s, dest: %s, in_port: %s", dpid, src, dst, in_port)
        # learn a mac address to avoid FLOOD next time.
        self.mac_to_port[dpid][src] = in_port
        if eth.ethertype == ether_types.ETH_TYPE_ARP:
            self.receive_arp(datapath,pkt,eth,in_port)
        #learn mac to ip 
        if eth.ethertype == ether_types.ETH_TYPE_IP:
            ipv4_pak = pkt.get_protocol(ipv4.ipv4)
            icmp_pak = pkt.get_protocol(icmp.icmp)
            self.logger.info('packet_in_handler: --> %s'%ipv4_pak)
            if dst == ROUTER_MACADDR1:
                out_port = 2
                actions.append( OFPActionSetField(eth_src=ROUTER_MACADDR2) )
                actions.append( OFPActionSetField(eth_dst='b2:64:b7:5f:5a:97') )

            elif dst == ROUTER_MACADDR2:
                out_port = 1
                actions.append( OFPActionSetField(eth_src=ROUTER_MACADDR1) )
                actions.append( OFPActionSetField(eth_dst='a2:86:fb:29:dc:57 ') )
            else:
                self.logger.info('Not working')
                return
            out = parser.OFPPacketOut(datapath = datapath,
                                      buffer_id = ofproto.OFP_NO_BUFFER,
                                      in_port = in_port,
                                      actions = actions,
                                      data = msg.data)
            self.logger.info('packet_out:--> %s'%out)
            datapath.send_msg(out)
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue was that in my code, when I was setting the actions variable, I did:

```
 actions = [parser.OFPActionOutput(port=port)]
```

then:

```
actions.append( OFPActionSetField(eth_src=ROUTER_MACADDR2) )
actions.append( OFPActionSetField(eth_dst='b2:64:b7:5f:5a:97') )
```

Hence the openflow switch would first send the packet out the port, then modify what was in it and then do nothing. The output port action should be the last specified.